# ReadOnly property in c# getting prices of items from enum

Tags: c#, enums, readonly

Price: A readonly property (i.e. it has only a get and no set) of type decimal which is 1.00 for small, 2.00 for medium, 3 for large, and 0.50 for cheese. I have the enum set up which is size but I'm confused on how to do this to get prices. I think i got the readonly property set up right just not sure how to calculate prices inside of it or maybe have to do it on the outside. Thank you.

```
public class Chili
{
    public Size Size { get; set; }
    public bool Cheese = false;
    public decimal Price
    {
        get
        {
            if(Size == Size.Small)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what is your question exactly since you already return '1' for small size, you can do that for other sizes as well using the same way. Could you share your Enum class?

Answer (score 3):

Switch statements or switch expressions (beginning with C# 8.0) are more suitable in conjunction with enums. Let us assume the enum

```cs
public enum Size { Small, Medium, Large }
```

Then you can write

```cs
public decimal Price
{
    get {
        decimal price = PlateSize switch {
            Size.Small => 1.00m,
            Size.Medium => 2.00m,
            Size.Large => 3.00m,
            _ => 0m
        };
        if (Cheese) {
            price += 0.50m;
        }
        return price;
    }
}
```

The last case in the switch expression is the default case that applies when none of the other cases applies. The C# compiler does not ensure enums to always have valid values. You can write `PlateSize = (Size)-1;` for instance or add new enum values in a future release and forget to adapt the switch expression. Maybe it is even better to throw an exception in such a case. You can do so by using a throw-expression:

```cs
decimal price = PlateSize switch {
    Size.Small => 1.00m,
    Size.Medium => 2.00m,
    Size.Large => 3.00m,
    _ => throw new NotImplementedException("Unexpected Size")
};
```

Note that a value given as e.g., `1.50` is a `double`. The `m` denotes a `decimal` value.

`Cheese` should be a property as well

```cs
public bool Cheese { get; set; }
```

In C# class fields and properties are initialized to their default value which happens to be `false` for a `bool`. So, the explicit initialization is not required. But if you want to be explicit, you can:

```cs
public bool Cheese { get; set; } = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write anything you like in get block just like in a method.

```
public class Chili
{
    public Size PlateSize { get; set; }
    public bool Cheese { get; set; }
    public decimal Price
    {
        get
        {
            decimal price = 0m;
            if(PlateSize == Size.Small)
            {
                price=1;
            }
            if(PlateSize == Size.Medium)
            {
                price=2;
            }
            if(PlateSize == Size.Large)
            {
                price=3;
            }
            if(Cheese)
            {
                price+=0.5m;
            }
            return price;
        }
    }
}
```

When you create instance of this class

```
var order=new Chili(){
    PlateSize = Size.Medium,
    Cheese = true
};
var price = order.Price;//2.5
```

Comment: It is okay to use `if`; however, with exception of the `Cheese` if, the other ifs should be combined with `else`, as only one of them can apply.

Comment: Also the compiler will tell you that `price` may not be assigned in the Cheese part and return statement.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes if only one of them can apply why use else?

Comment: If there was a `return` statement in the ifs, then `else` would not be necessary. But now, all the three `PlateSize` tests are performed.  E.g., if `PlateSize == Size.Small` then the two remaining tests are not necessary but are still performed. If there was an `else` between them, then they just would be skipped instead and then only the `Cheese` test would be executed next (of course there must be no `else` before the cheese test). `if(PlateSize == Size.Small) { price=1; } else if(PlateSize == Size.Medium) { price=2; } else { price=3; }`